# perl 5.26.3:how to set option for 32bit in Configure so that I will get perl compiled binary for 32 bit(i686-linux) for RHEL

Tags: perl, configure, 32-bit

I compiled perl 5.26.3 source code for RHEL from cpan link:

```
wget https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.26.3.tar.bz2
```

I compiled it with steps mentioned below:

```
    ./Configure -des -Dprefix=</path/to/install/>
     make
     make test
     make install
```

Then inside bin folder generated under </path/to/install/>

```
./perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux
```

What I see in Configure logs is it autodetected architecture as 64bit:

```
What is your architecture name [x86_64-linux]
```

I want to know, how to set option for 32bit so that I will get perl compiled binary of version 5.26.3 for 32bit.
And should give result as :
`built for i686-linux` instead of `built for x86_64-linux`

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/629474/105002

Comment: @choroba Let me check but the link you shared is also referring to centos, I am doing it for RHEL Linux. I got one link() there also it was mentioned that it worked for CENTOS only but let me try.